# Append line to previous line when it starts with '200'

Tags: python

My Problem is the following:
I have a csv-file with lines that normally start with '200'.
In this file there are unwanted linebreaks.

E.g.

```
200 Peter Pan 
200 John Smith 
200 Susan Murray 
200 Harald  
Williams
200 Liam Noah
```

That's how the file should look at the end:

```
200 Peter Pan
200 John Smith
200 Susan Murray
200 Harald Williams
200 Liam Noah
```

So whenever a line does not start with '200' it should be appended to the previous line.
I hope this should be quite easy with Python but I'm not getting it right so far.

Comment: You should have a go at writing some code yourself and post a specific question about any problem that you have.

Comment: Hint: replace newlines with space and split on `200`.

Comment: I'm sure i've seen almost the same question last week =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(<file_name>, 'r+') as file:
    text = str();
    for line in file:
        if line[0:3] == "200":
            text = "{}\n{}".format(text, line.strip());
        else:
            text = "{} {}".format(text, line.strip());
    file.seek(0);
    file.write(text[1:]);
```

Comment: I've edited it so that it doesn't put a redundant blank line at the beginning of the text.

Comment: Semicolons are generally not required, nor desirable, in Python. `text = ''` is preferred to `text = str()`.

Comment: Also, an extra space is added to each line.

Comment: So the code works fine but mhawke is right, an extra space is added at the end of each line. Therefore I wonder why you put in this part of code: + line.strip() + ' ' ?

Comment: Sorry, for sure we need the line.strip() but not the ' '

Comment: I added it so that the names wouldn't be added together with no space, but not very well apparently as it was first thing in the morning. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the job...

With a `file` called `file.csv`, with contents:

```
200 Peter Pan 
200 John Smith 
200 Susan Murray 
200 Harald  
Williams
200 Liam Noah
```

after we run the following `script`:

```
lines = open("file.csv", "r").read().split("\n")
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
   if not line.startswith("200"):
      lines[i-1] = lines[-1].strip() + " " + line
      lines.pop(i)

open("file.csv", "w").write("\n".join(lines)+"\n")
```

the `file` is updated as you wanted it to be to:

```
200 Peter Pan
200 John Smith
200 Susan Murray
200 Harald Williams
200 Liam Noah
```

**How does it work?**

The steps:

- read in the `.csv` file as a `string` and convert it to a `list` of `lines` by `splitting` the `string` on the new-line (`'\n'`) character.
- iterate through the `enumerated` `lines` `list` so we have two `variables` to work with: the `index and the`lines.
- check if the `line` starts with `"200"`.
- if it does, `append` the `line` to the `line` one `index` before (by `stripping` the `line` before and adding a space between), and then remove the `line` from the `list` of `lines` by `popping` its `index`.
- finally, we `open` the same `.csv` `file` for `writing` and `write` to it the new `lines`. The `string` from the `list` of the `lines` is got by adding a new-line character between each `line` and finally adding an extra one at the end.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

The code that works perfectly fine for me is the following:

```
with open('testing2.CSV', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = str();
    for line in file:
        if line[0:3] == "200":
            text = text + '\n';
        text = text + line.strip();
    file.seek(0);
    file.write(text);
```

It even keeps the first line which is nice as my CSV file has headers. Thanks to everyone who helped here especially Benjamin James Drury and Joe Iddon.

Answer (score 0):

Read csv file and iterate over lines:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    # header = next(f_csv)
    for row in f_csv:
        if not row.startswith(200):
            #append previous row
```